# Getting all existing piplines from an Azure Machine Learning Workspace

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I use azure machine learning services (aml) to run a ml-model. When I go to the GUI of AML I can see all the exisiting piplines, but I can't see how they are scheduled. I need to get all puplished piplines and the belonging meta data.

How I can get information about an existing pipline with the python sdk?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From azureml.pipeline.core.schedule import **ScheduleRecurrence**, **Schedule.list(ws)** to get information about an existing pipeline with the python sdk.

Azure documentation about [Schedule Recurrence class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.schedulerecurrence?view=azure-ml-py) and [Schedule.list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-core/azureml.pipeline.core.schedule(class)?view=azure-ml-py#list-workspace--active-only-true--pipeline-id-none--pipeline-endpoint-id-none---workflow-provider-none---service-endpoint-none-).

Answer (score 0):

once published a pipeline and was able to see from notebook.

Every publish will create a REST endpoint as shown [here](https://github.com/balakreshnan/Samples2021/blob/main/AzureMLPipelineNotebook/notebookpipelineexec.md).

```
published_pipeline1 = pipeline_run1.publish_pipeline(
     name="Published_Titanic_Pipeline_Notebook",
     description="Titanic_Pipeline_Notebook Published Pipeline Description",
     version="1.0")
```

Metadata from Azure ML: You can enable [Web service schema (OpenAPI specification)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-consume-web-service?tabs=python#web-service-schema-openapi-specification) in the service and consume it by querying the swagger URL of the service.